# How use Dozer with springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, dozer

I trying to integrate the dozer with springboot (https://dozermapper.github.io/gitbook/documentation/springBootIntegration.html)  but something is wrong:

I only put the dependency in my pom.xml

and try this:

```
public class ModeloController {

    private ModeloService modeloService;
    private Mapper dozerBeanMapper;

    @Autowired
    public ModeloController(ModeloService modeloService, Mapper dozerBeanMapper) {
        this.modeloService = modeloService;
        this.dozerBeanMapper = dozerBeanMapper;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public List<ModeloVO> listarTodos(){
        List<ModeloVO> retorno = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Modelo> banco = modeloService.listarTodos();
        retorno = dozerBeanMapper.map(banco, List.class);
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

in my Class Modelo I have 3 props, id, name and modelo, and in my ModeloVo I have only 2 props Id and name,

the dozer transform my retorno in a ArrayList of Modelo.class and not a list of ModeloVO with only the 2 fields

Answer (score 0):

The call being made to Dozer in your example is to map an instance of a List (first argument) to a new List.class (second argument). Dozer is doing as instructed and mapping a List to a new List instance with all of the same elements.
If you were to call Dozer's map method with the first argument being a single Modelo instance and the second argument as ModeloVo.class, it would map the single instance.
Last I checked, Dozer did not have a good facility for mapping arbitrary collections. There are two ways I can think (and have utilized) to accomplish this:
1) Loop through the source List, banco, calling Dozer's map method on each Modelo object, and adding the resulting ModeloVO object to a new List that you have instantiated.
2) Create a pair of wrapper classes for each, and provide a mapping to Dozer which provides the hints of the source type and target type.

The first option comes with some overhead as each call into Dozer requires some extra processing. The second option is more efficient from a processing perspective and could be the better option if the List is large and calling Dozer in a loop  would drag performance.